# Android ViewRoot NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

This causes the error:

```
this.addContentView(view, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

Not sure what the problem is, here is the trace:

```
ViewRoot.draw(boolean) line: 1440   
ViewRoot.performTraversals() line: 1172 
ViewRoot.handleMessage(Message) line: 1736  
ViewRoot(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
Looper.loop() line: 143 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4701    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 521  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 860  
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 618 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

Here is my code:

```
    public class LiveTabGroup extends ActivityGroup implements MoveToScreenNotification.handler
{

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        EventBus.subscribe(MoveToScreenNotification.class, this);

        View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("CameraListView", new Intent(this,CameraListView.class).
                addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)).getDecorView();

        this.setContentView(view);

    }

    @Override
    public void onMoveToScreenNotification(MoveToScreenNotification notif) 
    {
        if (notif.newScreen == MoveToScreenNotification.SCREEN_MOVIEPLAYER_LIVE)
        {
            SugarLoafSingleton.currentCamera.url = notif.videoURL;
            // Throw UI management on main thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            public void run()
            {
                StartPlayer();
            }
            });

        }

    }

    public void StartPlayer()
    {
        View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("VideoPlayer", new Intent(this,VideoPlayerView.class).
                addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)).getDecorView();
        this.addContentView(view, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));


    }


}
```

Comment: What Android version are you running on?

Comment: Did you check that the activity is actually starting? It may be that view is null.

Comment: Targeting Android 2.2 .  What do you mean by checking if the activity is starting?  I have debugged it, and my onCreate is called for the activity.  So i'm running this on the mainUI thread, I use the "this" keyword...is it referencing my LiveTabGroup instance as it I want it to?  And with that in mind, how would I reference a specific activity without using "this"?

Comment: `this` will refer to the LiveTabGroup instance. The onCreate method also is from that `ActivityGroup`. I'm asking if the `CameraListView` activity is starting. the `View view` refers to that Activity, so I'm asking if that is null. You can check it easily as `if (view == null) Log.d ("LiveTabGroup", "here is the problem");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd highly suggest reworking the way you're using the video player activity. If you just want to play a video, use the `VideoView` and embed it in an XML layout. <del>The way you're starting an activity and stealing its view looks like you're trying to work around the framework, which is going to lead to all sorts of wacky errors like this.</del>It seems as though I didn't understand `ActivityGroup`s very well. Still, I think this could probably be simplified somehow.

Comment: What's mediaplayer view? I guess you meant videoview?

Comment: Yeah, I meant a video view. Corrected in the answer text.